# The HTML document file type (text / html) is not supported wicked pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I try to export a pdf with gem wicked_pdf but no show correct the pdf , if I tried to open this file , show me a message 
The HTML document file type (text / html) is not supported

this is my controller

```
 def cuadro_pago_proveedores_tiempo

    authorize :reporte, :cuadro_pago_proveedores_tiempo?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.pdf {render template: '/reportes/pdf/pago_proveedores_tiempo'}
    end  
  end
```

This is my gemfile

gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

And my file /reportes/pdf/pago_proveedores_tiempo

```
<h1>Hi is a demo</h1>
```

My link to open this file is this

```
<%= link_to  "hola", "/reportes/" + tipo_reporte +".pdf" %>
```

When tipo_reporte is the param with name the report

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you go to the path using the `.pdf` format? This exception is most likely raised because you visited http://localhost:3000/your/path instead of http://localhost:3000/your/path.pdf. As you can see in your controller you only support `js` and `pdf` for this reason the exception is thrown. If you're using a Rails helper to generate the path you can provided the format like so: `some_path(format: :pdf)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the name of the file with pdf: in controller

this solved my problem

```
def cuadro_pago_proveedores_tiempo

    authorize :reporte, :cuadro_pago_proveedores_tiempo?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.pdf {render template: '/reportes/pdf/pago_proveedores_tiempo', pdf: "NameOfThePDF"}
    end  
  end
```